# Options for custom excel calculator on website

Tags: javascript, html, excel, office365, calculator

I'm trying to add a range of custom calculators that I have developed in excel to my website.
Some of them are rather complicated and large tables, and I have quite a lot of them.

I would like users to be able to enter data into certain cells to perform the calculations, download the tables as hardcoded .xlxs (i.e. formulas should be removed), and download pdf's of them directly from the page.

The options I have tried so far is either embedding the sheets or workbooks with excel-online (the problem with this is that the download function that comes with it downloads the entire workbook or sheet with all formulas. Is it possible to make a script to export hardcoded data from this iframe embedded document?) or completely rewriting each table calculator with html and javascript (Im reluctant to do this as I will have so many to do).

Any other options or advice would really be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that I see it, you have 3 options.

1. IFrame Excel Online, let the users do everything there, let them download the .xlsx file - which would mean that they would have the formulas.
2. Mock up Excel Online interface, so you won't end up working with the real excel stuff. After the inputting the data user can download a pre-computed version of the excel sheet, you won't expose your calculator functionalities.
3. Create an Excel add-in. You can do this in 2 ways, either a VSTO add-in or a Web Add-in. This way, you don't expose the functionality of your calculators, but still give the users the capability to use them. Web add-ins are cross platform and are pretty neat, but if you're doing really heavy computing you might need to look into VSTO.

Comment: Hi Mavi

Thank you for your help.
As I am trying to use this to increase traffic to my website (but not give away my formulas), it seems I will have to go with option 2.
But thanks for informing me about option 3, I think this might be very useful at a later stage.

Comment: Would you consider this a valid answer then? (Wondering if you'd hit the green tick there ;) )